# A dyadic decomposition of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable with mean equal to zero. We consider $n$ identical copies $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ of $X$ and denote with $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ the sum of them.   We decompose the $X_j$ into a dyadic decomposition: $$X_j=X_{j,0}+\sum_{m=1}^\infty X_{j,m}$$where $X_{j,0}:=X_j I(X_j\leq 1)$ and $X_{j,m} := X_j I(2^{m-1}<X_j<2^m)$, $I$ denoting the indicator function. In a similar way we split
$$S_n=S_{n,0}+\sum_{m=1}^\infty S_{n,m}$$ with  $S_{n,m}=\sum_{j=1}^n X_{j,m}$.

---

My question is: Why does the inequality $$P(|S_n|\geq C n)\leq \sum_{m=0}^\infty P \left(|S_{n,m}|\geq \dfrac{Cn}{100(m+1)^2}\right)$$ where $C$ denotes an arbitrary positive constant, hold ? I have a hint to use the pigeonhole principle and to apply the fact that the probability of the union of events is less then the sum of the probabilities of each of the events (i.e. rather elementary facts).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define for $m\geqslant 0$ the event 
$$E_m:=\left\{|S_{n,m}|\lt \frac{Cn}{100(m+1)^2}\right\}.$$
Then 
$$\tag{*}\bigcap_{m\geqslant 0}E_m\subset \{|S_n|\lt Cn\}.$$
Indeed, if $\omega\in \bigcap_{m\geqslant 0}E_m$, then for each $m\geqslant 0$, 
$|S_{n,m}(\omega)|\lt\frac{Cn}{100(m+1)^2}$. Noticing that $S_n=\sum_{m\geqslant 0}S_{n,m}$ and that $\sum_{m\geqslant 0}\frac{1}{100(m+1)^2}\lt 1$, 
we get $(*)$. 
It follows that 
$$\mathbb P\{|S_n|>cn\}\leqslant \mathbb P\left(\bigcup_{m\geqslant 0}E_m^c\right)\leqslant \sum_{m\geqslant 0}\mathbb P(E_m^c).$$